# AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'iter_rows'

Tags: python, django

I'd read an excel file, there I'm getting all sheets but when doing this
getting that error.

views.py

```
from Django.shortcuts import render
import openpyxl


def index(request):
    if "GET" == request.method:
        return render(request, 'file/index.html', {})
    else:
        excel_file = request.FILES["excel_file"]

        # you may put validations here to check extension or file size

        wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(excel_file)

        # getting all sheets
        worksheet = wb.sheetnames
        print(worksheet)

        excel_data = list()
        # iterating over the rows and
        # getting value from each cell in row
        for row in worksheet.iter_rows():
            row_data = list()
            for cell in row:
                row_data.append(str(cell.value))
            excel_data.append(row_data)

        return render(request, 'file/index.html', {"excel_data": excel_data})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`worksheet = wb.sheetnames` actually returns the sheet names as **list**.

How you can get the sheet:

```
if 'sheet name' in wb.sheetnames:
    sheet = wb['sheet name']
```

You can do the following one:

```
for name in wb.sheetnames:
    sheet = wb[name]
    for row in sheet.iter_rows():
        # Your code
```

**Update (Saving into DB):**:
If a sheet corresponds to a model and you want to save data into DB then see the following section:

```
sheet_to_model = {
    'sheet1':{
        'model': Model1, 
        'column_map': {
            'xl column 1': 'model_field_1',
            'xl column 2': 'model_field_2',
        }
    }

}

# Also map each sheet's column name to your model's field name

for name in wb.sheetnames:
    sheet = wb[name]
    for row in sheet.iter_rows():
        # Here get model name using sheet name and the sheet_to_model dict. 
        # Get each cell value from row and column name and create a dict using  
        # the model's field name and the cell value. Then inset using Model.objects.create(**data)
```

**Update 2 (Saving into DB):**
Suppose your xl file has the following sheets and corresponding columns:

- Sheet1 (Columns: 's1c1', 's1c2', 's1c3')
- Sheet1 (Columns: 's1c1', 's1c2', 's1c3')

And you have the models maned `Model1` and `Model2`. Data of `Sheet1` will be saved into `Model` and data of `Sheet2` into `Model2` Now, see the following code to understand how data is stored in corresponding model:

```
import openpyxl
from django import models


class Model1(models.Model):
    m1f1 = models.IntergerField()
    m1f2 = models.IntergerField()
    m1f3 = models.IntergerField()


class Model2(models.Model):
    m2f1 = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    m2f2 = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    m2f3 = models.CharField(max_length=128)


sheet_to_model = {
    'Sheet1':{
        'model': Model1, 
        'columns': ['s1c1', 's1c2', 's1c3'],
        'column_map': {
            's1c1': 'm1f1',
            's1c2': 'm1f2',
            's1c3': 'm1f3',
        }
    }, 
    'Sheet2':{
        'model': Model2, 
        'columns': ['s2c1', 's2c2', 's2c3'],
        'column_map': {
            's2c1': 'm2f1',
            's2c2': 'm2f2',
            's2c3': 'm2f3',
        }
    }

}

wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('./datas.xlsx')

print(wb.sheetnames)

for sheet_name in wb.sheetnames:
    sheet = wb[sheet_name]
    for index, row in enumerate(sheet.iter_rows()):
        data = {}
        if index: # First row is columns name
            for idx2, col in enumerate(row):
                # print(col.value)
                p = sheet_to_model[sheet_name]['columns'][idx2]
                # print(p)
                data[sheet_to_model[sheet_name]['column_map'][p]] = col.value
            # print(data)
            sheet_to_model[sheet_name]['model'].objects.create(**data)
```

You can also learn and use [Pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/) to handle this types of situations more easily.

Comment: Tnx bro, it's working cool. actually, am showing this data in HTML page but I don't have an idea to store this data to DB can u tell this

Comment: If data of a sheet is related to a model then you can map the sheet name to model (e.g., {'sheet1': Model1, 'sheet2': model2}). Then when reading sheets, for each sheet, insert each row to the sheet's corresponding model. see **Update** section of my answer. If my answer helps you solve the problem, then I hope you'll mark it as Accepted.

Comment: thnx for this bro, bro tell me what should I write on their model.py file, can you plz wrote that code it will help, thnx in advance

Comment: can u completely write that model.py code I'm not understanding so?

Comment: see **Update 2** section for full code and explanation.

Comment: bro, I check that code but we have to specify the directory of a file but I don't want like this, I need to be when am choosing any excel file that files having some sheets that data will update in DB

Comment: read InmemoryUploadedFile:  
```
if form.is_valid():
       data = form.cleaned_data   
        inmemory_uploaded_file = data['upload_file_as_excel']
```
Here, `upload_file_as_excel` is the form's field name. 
Now, read like `wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(inmemory_uploaded_file )`

Comment: send me ur watsapp number bro. i want to chat with u.

Answer (score 1):

As per documentation, [**`wb.sheetnames`**](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/openpyxl.workbook.workbook.html?highlight=get_sheet_by_name#openpyxl.workbook.workbook.Workbook.sheetnames) returns sheet names which is a list, you need to select a sheet first, then you can use `iter_rows`. For example:

If you want to use first sheet:

```
sheet_name = wb.sheetnames[0]
worksheet = wb[sheet_name]
for row in worksheet.iter_rows():
   ...
```

Or if you want to go through all sheets:

```
for sheet_name in wb.sheetnames:
    worksheet = wb[sheet_name]
    for row in worksheet.iter_rows():
        # rest of the code
```

#### Saving to DB

For saving, you can use a model. Lets say you have a model named `WBData`, which has fields to match the columns, then you can save it like this:

```
for row in worksheet.iter_rows():
    row_data = list()
    for cell in row:
        row_data.append(str(cell.value))
    WBData.objects.create(field1=row_data[0], field2=row_data[1],...)
```

Comment: tnx, bro, it's working fine. bro, I have more question actually I'm showing this data in my HTML page, how to store data to DB

Comment: thnx for this bro,  bro tell me what should I write on their model.py file, can you plz wrote that code it will help, thnx in advance

Comment: can u completely write that model.py code I'm not understanding so?

Comment: I can't write because i don't know whats on the xls file. Its better if you can check the documentation: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/models/

Comment: the excel file containing only (1, company name. 2, Category. 3, CN_Number.)

Comment: bro are u using skype if ur using means send me name or send me wtsapp number

Answer (score 0):

```
for name in work_book.sheetnames:
    sheet = work_book[name]
    for row in sheet.iter_rows():
        # Your code
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?

Comment: Ooh, was first answer for me, I will keep that in mind for next time.